# How to Change 302 Redirect to 301 Redirect in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here's the code I have in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /special/service
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://clients.example.com/aff.php?aff=$1&p=service.php [R,NC]
```

When I go the my redirect while running FireBug I'm seeing that it's actually a 302 redirect for some reason.  What do I need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `=301` in your flags:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /special/service
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://clients.example.com/aff.php?aff=$1&p=service.php [R=301,NC]
```