# Wordpress admin page .htaccess exceptions

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website made with wordpress (it's a multilingual site) and I'm modifying the .htaccess file in order to make some redirections. My page now is for example: https://example.es

And I'd like to redirect everything to this page (even if you type example.es/en or www.example.es/en or http://www.example.es/es ... all the variants)

My .htaccess now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} jh73820h.htm$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.es/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It works but when I try to go to my admin page in Wordpress (https://example.es/wp-admin/) I'm being redirect to https://example.es/es/wp-admin/ or https://example.es/en/wp-admin/.

Does anybody know how can I make an exception for this page? I don't want to be redirect when the site is wp-admin, it should be like this: https://example.es/wp-admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin` before `RewriteEngine on`.

If it doesn't works follow the link below; put `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin`before `# BEGIN Wordpress`

Look here:
[Redirect Visitors to new url but exclude images and admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923064/redirect-visitors-to-new-url-but-exclude-images-and-admin)

Comment: It works on the first way! Thanks a lot! I think that I have some 302 redirection in this code, and I'd like all of them to be 301, what should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706217/how-to-change-302-redirect-to-301-redirect-in-htaccess
@Anna

Comment: There's alot of relevant links on the right side of that answer, you could look at those if this does not help